# Noninteractive script running over ssh is interrupted as apt-get finishes

Tags: shell-script, apt, system-installation, lxc

When I run the following non interactive script on Ubuntu Server 13.04 it's interrupted 
when **lxc-docker** package finishes installation.

Script :

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeychecking=no -t -t -i $CERT $USER@$SERVER <<'ENDSSH'

sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install software-properties-common
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive add-apt-repository -y ppa:dotcloud/lxc-docker
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y update
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install lxc-docker

echo "some other actions here..."

exit #SSH session

ENDSSH
exit
```

Everything seems to be fine but then the script is interrupted after this line in the output :

```
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

**1) Why is this happenning? How can I prevent that?**

**2) If not, how I can detect that ssh session has finished unsucessfully?**

Last lines from installation (shortened) :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bridge-utils bsdtar cgroup-lite debootstrap dnsmasq-base libapparmor1
  libarchive13 libcap2-bin liblxc0 liblzo2-2 libnetfilter-conntrack3
  libnettle4 libpam-cap libseccomp1 lxc lxc-templates python3-lxc
Suggested packages:
  bsdcpio lrzip libcap-dev btrfs-tools lvm2 lxctl qemu-user-static
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bridge-utils bsdtar cgroup-lite debootstrap dnsmasq-base libapparmor1
  libarchive13 libcap2-bin liblxc0 liblzo2-2 libnetfilter-conntrack3
  libnettle4 libpam-cap libseccomp1 lxc lxc-docker lxc-templates python3-lxc
0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,495 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,742 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main liblzo2-2 amd64 2.06-1build1 [53.2 kB]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libnettle4 amd64 2.4-3 [94.7 kB]
.
.
.
.
.
.
Setting up libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64 (1.0.1-1) ...
Setting up dnsmasq-base (2.65-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-lxc (0.9.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up lxc (0.9.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
lxc start/running
Setting up lxc dnsmasq configuration.
Setting up bsdtar (3.1.2-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcap2-bin (1:2.22-1.2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libpam-cap:amd64 (1:2.22-1.2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up cgroup-lite (1.8) ...
cgroup-lite start/running
Setting up debootstrap (1.0.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up lxc-docker (0.4.0-1) ...
docker start/running, process 2444
Setting up lxc-templates (0.9.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

Comment: What happens if you just try to install lxc-doctor normally on one of the machines?

Answer (score 1):

Just to state the obvious (as a work-around, not a proper solution), maybe try to scp the script to the server, and then execute the script...?

```
$ cat<<ENDSSH > /tmp/tmp.sh
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get ...
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install lxc-docker
echo "some other actions here..."
exit
ENDSSH
```

And then,

```
$ scp  /tmp/tmp.sh ${USER}@${SERVER}:/tmp/tmp.sh \
  && ssh $USER@$SERVER 'chmod u+x /tmp/tmp.sh && /tmp/tmp.sh; rm /tmp/tmp.sh'
```

If that also terminates, then the remote commands may have to be run in the background, disconnect, followed by another ssh command to check the result of executing the script.